# Stack auto-removes dependency from .cabal file following 'stack build'

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, threepenny-gui

I want to work on a new Haskell project using the [threepenny-gui](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui) package.

The first thing I did was create a stack project via `$ stack new threepennydemo`. From here, here, I did the following:

1. I edited the extra-deps section in my stack.yaml file from:

```
# extra-deps: []
```

to

```
extra-deps:
  - threepenny-gui-0.9.0.0
```

2. I edited the .cabal file from:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_threepennydemo
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
  default-language: Haskell2010

executable threepennydemo-exe
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_threepennydemo
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , threepennydemo
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite threepennydemo-test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Spec.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_threepennydemo
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , threepennydemo
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

to

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_threepennydemo
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , threepenny-gui >= 0.9
  default-language: Haskell2010

executable threepennydemo-exe
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_threepennydemo
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , threepennydemo
    , threepenny-gui >= 0.9
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite threepennydemo-test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Spec.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_threepennydemo
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , threepennydemo
    , threepenny-gui >= 0.9
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

3. I edited the stock /app/Main.hs from:

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = someFunc
```

to

```
import Graphics.UI.Threepenny
main :: IO ()
main = do
 startGUI defaultConfig showMessage
showMessage :: Window -> UI ()
showMessage window = do
 getBody window #+ [string "Hello, world!"]
 return ()
```

4. I enter the command `$ stack build`.

From here, I notice two things. The first is that I receive the following error:

```
Building all executables for `threepennydemo' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
threepennydemo> configure (lib + exe)
Configuring threepennydemo-0.1.0.0...
threepennydemo> build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library for threepennydemo-0.1.0.0..
Building library for threepennydemo-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing executable 'threepennydemo-exe' for threepennydemo-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'threepennydemo-exe' for threepennydemo-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Main

/Users/my_username/threepennydemo/app/Main.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Graphics.UI.Threepenny’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘threepenny-gui-0.9.0.0’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘threepenny-gui’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Graphics.UI.Threepenny
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


--  While building package threepennydemo-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/my_username/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build lib:threepennydemo exe:threepennydemo-exe --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The second is that my .cabal file, edited as mentioned in 2., has automatically removed the edits I made to the file.

What am I missing in order to be able to use a third party library when setting up a new stack project?

Comment: `stack` probably generates the `threepennydemo.cabal` file from a `package.yaml` file. You can fix the situation by either adding the dependencies to the `package.yaml`, or by deleting the `package.yaml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My difficulty as the result of some confusion between `stack.yaml` and `package.yaml`. The latter being what generates the `threepennydemo.cabal` file. Hence, dependencies must also be specified to a `package.yaml` file. Adding this dependency to the `package.yaml` allowed `$ stack build` to complete without issue.

Comment: Alternately, you can delete `package.yaml` and just use `threepennydemo.cabal` for dependency management (which is what I do).